# Clear WooCommerce Cart with a Query String and Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, query-string, cart

I'm trying to use this code to redirect to a shop page and clear the cart using **`clear-cart`** query string but there is an issue I'm having. When it redirects to the shop page, the cart clears but when I try to "Add to Cart" a new product, it refreshes the page and clears the cart again. This is because the url contains the query string at the end of it now **`www.my-site.com/shop/?clear-cart`**. As I would like to have the option to add multiple items to the cart, is there a way that when it redirects it will remove the query string from the url? Or is there a better solution for this?

```
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart_url' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart_url() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following that uses `template_redirect` hook to first empty the cart and redirect to shop page (removing the query string):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'empty_cart_and_redirect' );
function empty_cart_and_redirect( $query ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['clear-cart'] ) ) {
        // 1. Empty cart
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();
        
        // 2. Redirect to Shop page
        $redirect_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
        wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). It should work.

---

to redirect to `corner-store`, try to use instead:

```
$redirect_url = home_url( '/corner-store/' );
```

Comment: This works, thank you. If I was to redirect to a 'corner-store' page, how would I do this? I've tried replacing the 'shop' `$redirect_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'corner-store' );` but it keeps redirecting to the home page. The url is `www.my-site.com/corner-store/?clear-cart`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have emptied the Cart you could call the header function.

```
header("Location: www.mysite.com/shop");
```